# how to install packages for node.js on windows without package manager?

Tags: windows, node.js, package

Normally when I go to node js website there is only one exe file to download. And I don't need to install many packages only one or two, so I don't need a manager. For Example I'm interested in it: https://npmjs.org/package/node-ffi - And what I'm supposed to do with that, download it and put it zipped in the same folder than node.exe ? Do it install creatin some registry keys or what ? Do I must have some type of compiler or git ?

Comment: Why not use `npm`? It is included with the standard Windows distribution of Nodejs. It keeps things properly organized, installed and updated easily. As one package may depend on another, you're going to potentially need to do a lot of manual work.

Comment: Where it is included ? There is only one node.exe file to download ? Is it included in there ? Do I have to run in from *.js file ?

Comment: Just grab the installer (msi): http://nodejs.org/download/ after installation, from a **newly** opened command prompt, `npm` will be in the path.

Comment: Yes, but that would not be portable install, it will leave information on my system partition and when I ghost it back, all this is gone.

Comment: What is "ghost it back"? You hadn't mentioned that you wanted a portable install.

Comment: It means to replace partition from backup. I got all the data on external drive and system on relatively small SSD. And I often back it up if I play too hard with it, so non portable apps are a little pain.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you need `node-ffi` I recommend that you use `npm` as you will find it easier to install other packages later and to handle upgrades to existing packages.

That being said to install `node-ffi` It seems like you will need to [compile C++ code](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi#installation) which means that it will be considerably easier (assuming you have setup your build tools compile C++ on Windows) then to install `node-ffi` by *hand*.

If you install the Node via the Windows installer you will get `npm` which is the official way to install packages.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you try to manage packages manually. You'll find it very cumbersome if you use more than a couple (and many packages will have other package dependencies that you'll need to locate correctly). If you want to have a portable install of NPM, you'll need to grab the source code for [NPM](https://npmjs.org/) from its [Github repository](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) (and you can just grab the zip download if you want):

```
https://github.com/isaacs/npm
```

Then, you should be able to use the `npm.cmd` file in the folder

```
\bin\npm.cmd
```

for NPM functionality. You might want to add it (and `node.exe`) to your environment path.